# How to avoid code duplication for input variable declaration/instantiation in Terraform?

Tags: terraform

I want to create a variable 'blueprint' and instantiate it several times. How do I achieve this?

Example :

```
my_project
|--main.tf
|--variables.tf
|--variables.tfvars
```

- In the `main.tf` I declare resources that use variables,
- In `variables.tf` module I want this sample variable

```
variable "project_info" {
  type = object({
    name = string
    id   = string
  })
}
```

- In `variables.tfvars` I want this (Kind of)

```
project_1_info = {
  name = "prj-1"
  id   = "prj-1-192388"
}

project_2_info = {
  name = "prj-2"
  id   = "prj-2-120917"
}
```

At the moment, what I declare in the `variables.tf` module is the following :

```
variable "project_1_info" {
  type = object({
    name = string
    id   = string
  })
}

variable "project_2_info" {
  type = object({
    name = string
    id   = string
  })
}
```

Which I find quite repetitive by duplicating declarations, makes maintenance and readability worse.

Any suggestions? Can this even be achieved with HCL?

Comment: Maybe making the variables with multiple declarations into an array or dictionary-like structure...? Feels like a gimmicky workaround

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually you would use [map](https://www.terraform.io/language/expressions/types#map) for that:

```
variable "project" {
  type = map(object({
    name = string
    id   = string
  }))
}
```

with a value:

```
project = {
  project1name = {
      name = "prj-1"
      id   = "prj-1-192388"
  },
  project2name = {
      name = "prj-2"
      id   = "prj-2-192388"
  },
  project3name = {
      name = "prj-3"
      id   = "prj-3-192388"
  }
}
```